# Weird behavior when checking for NaNs in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to loop over all the rows in a df, checking that two conditions hold and, if they do, replace the value in a column with something else. I've attempted to do this two different ways:

```
    if (sales.iloc[idx]['shelf'] in ("DRY BLENDS","LIQUID BLENDS")) & np.isnan(sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend']):
        sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend'] = False
```

and:

```
    if (sales.iloc[idx]['shelf'] in ("DRY BLENDS","LIQUID BLENDS")) & (sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend'] == np.NaN):
        sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend'] = False
```

By including print statements we've verified that the if statement is actually functional, but no assignment ever takes place. Once we've run the loop, there are True and NaN values in the 'traceable_blend' column, but never False. Somehow the assignment is failing.

It looks like this might've worked:

```
    if (sales.iloc[idx]['shelf'] in ("DRY BLENDS","LIQUID BLENDS")) & np.isnan(sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend']):
        sales.at[idx, 'traceable_blend'] = False
```

But I would still like to understand what's happening.

Comment: It's unlikely that an explicit loop is necessary here. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This has two separate bugs: a) **Comparing `== np.NaN` always fails**, by definition. Anyway, you don't even need to get and then use the index, so just use `df.fillna()` directly, instead of `df[col].isnull()`. b) **You're trying to assign by [index chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas), which only makes a copy, assigns to it, then just throws it away**. Anyway you don't need any of this, use `fillna()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, `sales.iloc[idx]['traceable_blend']=False`, is index chaining, and will almost never work. In fact, you don't need to loop:

```
sales['traceable_blend'] = sales['traceable_blend'].fillna(sales['shelf'].isin(['DRY BLENDS', 'LIQUID BLENDS']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas offers two functions for checking for missing data (NaN or null): `isnull()` and `notnull()` - They return a boolean value. I suggest to try these instead of `isnan()`

You can also determine if any value is missing in your series by chaining `.values.any()`